# Bitlocker: Create a USB startup key from a recover key file

Tags: bitlocker

I've encrypted the C: drive of one of my machines and lost the USB startup key.  I DID backup the Recovery Key .txt file.  How can I create a new USB startup key from this .txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I create a new USB startup key from this .txt file?

You cannot create the startup from that file.  You will have to run through the following process in order to create a new startup key.

> 1. Navigate to **All Control Panel Items -> BitLocker Drive Encryption**
>
> [image]
>
> 2. Click **Copy startup key** and go through the process of copying the startup key to a new flash drive.  DO NOT use the same key that
>      contains the recovery key, since that currently is your only method,
>      you can use to unlock your drive and access your data.

Source: [How to Copy Startup Key of OS Drive Encrypted by BitLocker in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97295-copy-startup-key-os-drive-encrypted-bitlocker-windows.html#option1)